# Linearization of logical AND of binary & integer decision variables in the IF condition

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to linearize following If-else constraint with many logical AND of binary & integer decision variables in the if condition.

$if(x_{i,k}=1\;AND\; x_{j,k}=1\; AND\; s[i]\leq s[j]\; AND\; cost[i]!=s[j]) then\\ temp[i][j]=y[i]-23.514$

where $x_{i,k}\;,x_{j,k}$ are binary decision variables and $s[i],\;s[j],\;cost[i],\;temp[i][j],\;y[j]$ are integer decision variables.

Can someone please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: In general you will have to break the different ANDs up into separate clauses and introduce a new binary variable for each, then string them together. More details about how to write "if [something] then $y=1$" can be found here: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/33/38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So effectively you have $\textbf{if } q \textbf{ then } f(x) = 0$. where $q$ is a complex expression $q = a \textbf{ and } b \textbf{ and } c \textbf{ and } d$ where some of the terms here come from inequalities.

$\textbf{if } q \textbf{ then } f(x) = 0$ can be written using the big-M model $-M(1-q) \leq f(x) \leq M(1-q)$

$q = a \textbf{ and } b \textbf{ and } c \textbf{ and } d$ is $q\geq a+b+c+d-3, q\leq a, q\leq b, q\leq c, q\leq d$.

$a$ and $b$ correspond to binary variables in your model, so already done,. i.e., just use those variables.

The variable corresponding to the binary $c$ is activated when some integer function $s_1(x)\leq 0$, which is can be modelled as $s(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}-Mc$

The variable corresponding to the binary $d$ is activated when some integer function $s_2(x)\ne 0$, which can be represented using two new binary variables $e$ and $f$ and the model $-Mf-\frac{1}{2}\leq s_2(x) \leq \frac{1}{2} + Me, d = e+f$

Comment: Thank you for this solution. As per my formulation, I will use $s_1(x)$ as $s[i]-s[j]\leq 0$. But I am not understanding that what will be my $s_2(x)$? Is it $cost[i]-s[j]\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Yes. And everything is of course repeated with new variables for every i, j,k combination

Comment: Sir, what will be the change in the formulation of above $d$ if I want to use the constraint as $cost[i]=s[j]$ instead of $cost[i]!=s[j]$ where $cost[i]$ and $s[j]$ are integer decision variables and remaining if else condition is same?

Comment: So you want $(s=0) \rightarrow d$. That would be $s\leq -\frac{1}{2} + Me, s\geq \frac{1}{2}-Mf , d  \geq e + f -1$

Comment: Thank you for this new solution. I just tried with $if(x_{i,k}=1\, AND\, cost[i]=s[j])then\, temp[i][j]=y[i]-23.514$, I used the formulation as, $if\,\, q\, \,then\, f(x)=0$ where $q=a\, AND\, d$ is $q\geq a+d-1, q\leq a, q\leq d$, $-M(1-q)\leq f(x)\leq M(1-q)$, $f(x) = temp[i][j]-(y[i]-23.514)$,  $s\leq -\frac{1}{2}+Me, s\geq \frac{1}{2}-Mf, d\geq e+f-1$ when q = 1 then I get correct answer but when q = 0 then I get $temp[i][j]=M+(y[i]-23.514)$. Please help me to correct this problem.

Comment: there seems to be problem in $-M(1-q)\leq f(x)\leq M(1-q)$. Please help me with this formulation.

Comment: I want $temp[i][j]=0$ when $q=0$

Comment: That's not what you model says as the result is undefined in your model when if the condition isn't true. If you want $t$ to be 0 when $q$ is zero, you must add the constraint $-Mq \leq t \leq Mq$. You should be able to start to see the general approach used now for controlling logic behavior.

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate you for sharing the knowledge and giving your precious time.

Comment: Sir, can you please give me the reference of this formulation tricks? I want to cite it in my research. Thank you.

Comment: I want, If q=1 then $temp[i][j=y[i]-23.514$ else $temp=0$. So I am using $-M(1-q)\leq (temp[i][j]-(y[i]-23.514))\leq M(1-q)$ and $-Mq\leq (temp[i][j]-0)\leq Mq$ but it's giving infeasible solution. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: So the problem is infeasible (or you are using an invalid value on $M$)

Comment: I am using the maximum possible value of $temp[i][j]$ as the value of M. Is it correct? Or do I need to take a more larger value?

Comment: You would have to take the largest possible value of (temp[i][j]−(y[i]−23.514)) into account too (in practice using different $M$ on the different constraints of course)

Comment: Thank you. I will do it.